# Prevent overlap of sticky footer inside fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Our site has a fixed sidebar *containing* a sticky footer. This worked fine when viewed on displays where the browser height was greater than the height of the sidebar content but on smaller displays the footer was "cut off".

To remedy this, I added a media query which would change the footer to be relatively positioned inside the sidebar and set `overflow: auto` on the sidebar:

```
/* sidebar padding + menu height + footer height */
@media screen and (max-height: 580px) {
    .sidebar .footer {
        position: relative;
    }
}
```

Although this at least allows the full sidebar content to be viewed on smaller displays it also means we end up with a scrollbar **on the sidebar** which doesn't look very nice.

What I would like to happen is that if the browser viewport is smaller than the height of the sidebar content you should be able to scroll using the **normal page scrollbar** to view all the content.

I imagine this is possible with a media query to change the `position` of the sidebar but I just can't seem to figure it out.

- Fiddle with full code: http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/pRBgT/
- Full screen result demonstrating the problem: http://fiddle.jshell.net/benfosterdev/pRBgT/show/light/

Comment: a little confused.  you're saying you don't like the scroll on the sidebar but then you say you want the normal scrollbar?  can you clarify the goal a little bit?

Comment: By "normal" scrollbar I mean the standard page scrollbar. Its much easier to understand if you look at the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be achieved with pure CSS, since what you're describing is a media query that specifies "If the viewport is under 580px height, fix the sidebar position until a certain scroll distance, then position it statically". Scrolling is a property that goes beyond the scope of media queries.

Building on Brad's answer - here's a quick way to do it with jQuery

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/nR6Fy/)

```
$(document).scroll(function(){    
    if ($(window).height()<=580){
        var sidebarObj=$(".sidebar");
        var extraSidebar=sidebarObj.height()-$(window).height();        
        if ($(document).scrollTop()>extraSidebar){            
            if (sidebarObj.css("position")!="fixed"){
                sidebarObj.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "top": -extraSidebar+"px"
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            sidebarObj.css({
                "position": "static",
                "top": 0+"px"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 2):

Understand now.  Had looked at the fiddle before the comments but still didn't quite get it :)

I think this is what you're looking for in your media query:

```
/* sidebar padding + menu height + footer height */
@media screen and (max-height: 580px) {
    .sidebar .footer {
        position: relative;
    }
    .sidebar{position: static; overflow:visible; float:left;}
}
```

key being the style on .sidebar

Comment: Again this works until you scroll down the page - at this point the sidebar needs to become fixed to the bottom again of the viewport again. I'm beginning to this is not possible without resorting to JavaScript.

Comment: @BenFoster In you ideal solution - when the viewport height is too small, the user scrolls down, until he reaches the footer, then the footer stops scrolling, and the page continues to scroll? Meaning the user sees the rest of the page with only the bottom part of the sidebar?

Comment: yeah...question wasn't super clear :) so to clarify, when the viewport gets small enough to cut off the footer, you want the PAGE to scroll until the sidebar footer is in full view, then have the sidebar remain fixed until you get to the bottom of the page, leaving the top of the menu cut off?